# Recuperar que dato se ha seleccionado de un <select> de un jsp y recuperarlo en un servlet

Tags: html, web

```
<select name="categorias">
 <option selected>SELECCIONE UNA CATEGORIA</option>
 <option value="1" >CIENCIAS DE LA COMPUTACIÓN</option>
 <option value="2" >QUÍMICA E INGENIERÍA DEL PETRÓLEO</option>
 <option value="3" >INGENIERÍA AMBIENTAL</option>
 <option value="4" >INGENIERÍA MECÁNICA</option>
 <option value="5" >INGENIERÍA CIVIL</option>
 <option value="6" >ELECTRÓNICA</option>
</select><br>
```

Quiero saber como recuperar el valor que el usuario selecciona y pasarlo a un servlet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola para que puedas recuperar los datos del formulario en el servlet

```
String categoria_seleccionada = request.getParameter("categorias");
```

donde "categorias" debe ser igual al nombre de tu combobox de tu jsp o de cualquier otro componete html como inputs definido como name="nombredecombobox".
y para que puedas enviar datos al jsp 
es el siguiente

```
 String mensaje= "hello";
 request.setAttribute("saludo",mensaje);
```

recueperas en tu jsp y lo imprimes

```
 <%String mensaje =(String)request.getAttribute("saludo");%>
<p><%=mensaje%> </p>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda